# GDAL Not Linking

Tags: c++, linker, gdal

I'm trying to get my program running on Windows. It depends on GDAL,  a library for loading GIS data. It compiles and links fine on both Linux and macOS. I'm using CMake with MinGW and I'm running into linking errors like this:

```
undefined reference to `GDALRasterBand::RasterIO(GDALRWFlag, int, int, int, int, void*, int, int, GDALDataType, long, long, GDALRasterIOExtraArg*)'
CMakeFiles\Routes.dir/objects.a(elevation.cpp.obj): In function `ZN13ElevationData9calcStatsEv':
C:/Users/Logan/Documents/Routes/src/elevation/elevation.cpp:138: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::GetRasterXSize()'
C:/Users/Logan/Documents/Routes/src/elevation/elevation.cpp:139: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::GetRasterYSize()'
CMakeFiles\Routes.dir/objects.a(elevation.cpp.obj): In function `ZN13ElevationData17createOpenCLImageEv':
C:/Users/Logan/Documents/Routes/src/elevation/elevation.cpp:206: undefined reference to `GDALRasterBand::RasterIO(GDALRWFlag, int, int, int, int, void*, int, int, GDALDataType, long, long, GDALRasterIOExtraArg*)'
```

I compiled GDAL with VS2017 and I've verified that it is installed where I am specifying in my CMake File. Here is the relevant portions of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
IF (WIN32)

  message(STATUS "Compiling for Windows")
  set(GDAL_LIBRARY "C:/warmerda/bld/lib/gdal_i.lib")
  set(GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/warmerda/bld/include/")

  find_package(OpenCL REQUIRED)
  include_directories(${OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ELSE()

...

message(STATUS ${GDAL_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(Routes ${GDAL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCL_LIBRARIES})
```

I almost never do development on Windows so I'm kind of stuck. I've tried linking against the dll as well with no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you're attempting to link a library you compiled with VC++ with object
files that you're compiling with GCC (MinGW). That doesn't work.
GCC and VC++ have different and incompatible [ABIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface),
and in particular different [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) protocols.
Hence the mangled function names emitted by MinGW in your object code will
not match any exported by your VC++ compiled library. You will need to
build the GDAL library with MinGW.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out after a little while, but forgot about the question I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @MikeKinghan! I had been pulling my hair out for couple of days! Your answer clicked right away. For those who want to have no headache with the libraries, just use MSYS2 (msys2.org). Then using `pacman` in the msys2 command prompt, get the MingW (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`) and GDAL (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdal`).

Comment: Could you give some detail what your cmakelists.txt looked like after using the msys method? I'm having the same issue but can't figure out how to link to GDAL through msys.

Comment: Hey @RossWardrup, I use vscode and setup my build and debug using g++ there. I don't use the cmakelists.txt. But if it helps, this is how it compiles and builds based on my settings. (I am using boost and curl; they are all coming with the msys2. Just search for the package you need.C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -m64 'c:/VSCodeProjects/test/*.cpp' 
-o 'c:/VSCodeProjects/test/Bin/main.exe' 
-I 'c:/VSCodeProjects/test' 
-I C:/msys64/mingw64/include 
-I C:/msys64/mingw64/include/boost 
-L C:/msys64/mingw64/bin -l libgdal-26 -l libcurl-4 -l libboost_filesystem