# Undefined reference when trying to compile with GDAL's GDALDataset::GetLayers()

Tags: c++, gdal, undefined-reference

I'm trying to compile some code involving GDAL but keep getting errors. It looks like `GetLayers` is defined in gdal_priv.h, but Clion reports that the file doesn't belong to any project target, which I'm suspicious about. [According to this](https://gdal.org/doxygen/classGDALDataset.html#a8cfa4d17c68e441614118931b17cd7fa), it should work. Other methods of `poDS` work, such as `GetLayerByName`. Any ideas on where I can look? I am wondering if my cmakelists.txt is wrong.

Here's some example code. I'm aware that `poDS->GetFeatures();` is wrong, but I was just testing.

main.cpp

```
#include "DisplayShapefile.h"
#include <iostream>

GDALDataset * Shapefile::read(const char *path) {
    // Read shapefile from filesystem
    GDALAllRegister();
    GDALDataset *poDS;

    poDS = (GDALDataset*) GDALOpenEx(path, GDAL_OF_VECTOR, NULL, NULL,  NULL);

    if( poDS == NULL ) {
        printf( "Open failed.\n" );
        exit ( 1 );
    }
    poDS->GetFeatures();
    return poDS;
}

int Shapefile::get_layer_count(GDALDataset *dataset) {
    // Get layer count contained by shapefile
    return GDALDatasetGetLayerCount(dataset);
}

std::vector<std::string> Shapefile::layer_names(GDALDataset *dataset) {
    std::vector<std::string> names;
    for( auto&& poLayer: dataset->GetLayers() ) {
        std::string name = poLayer->GetName();
        names.push_back(name);
        std::cout << "Layer " << name << std::endl;
    }
    return names;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

cmakelists

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(gdalTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\msys64\\mingw64")

find_package(GDAL REQUIRED)
include_directories ( include ${GDAL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES C:/OSGeo4W64/include/gdal_priv.h)

add_executable(gdalTest main.cpp DisplayShapefile.h ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(gdalTest ${GDAL_LIBRARIES})
```

The error I get is:

```
CMakeFiles\gdalTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Shapefile::read(char const*)':
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::GetFeatures()'
CMakeFiles\gdalTest.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `Shapefile::layer_names[abi:cxx11](GDALDataset*)':
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::GetLayers()'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::begin() const'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::end() const'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::operator!=(GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator const&) const'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::operator*() const'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::operator++()'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::~Iterator()'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::~Iterator()'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::~Iterator()'
C:/Users/rwardrup/CLionProjects/gdalTest/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to `GDALDataset::Layers::Iterator::~Iterator()'
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842468/gdal-not-linking ?

Comment: I overlooked the mingw environment I was using and it was all mismatched.